# RSA шифрование: коэффициент k

Tags: криптография, шифрование, rsa

В [видео Khan Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vooHjWxmcIE&t=452s) объясняют RSA шифрование. После всех вычислений мы получаем формулу закрытый ключ `d = (k*Phi(n)+1)/e`, причем было сказано что k это любое число. Однако потом в примере берется конкретный `k = 2`. Не до конца понял, мы действительно можем брать разные k и получить несколько закрытых ключей? Или мы выбираем такой k чтобы наш d был целым числом и т.п.? И всегда ли такое k существует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас вопрос состоит из нескольких подвопросов.

Начну с вопроса о том, сколько может быть приватных ключей.

Да, теоретически может быть несколько `d` таких, что `(m**e)**d == 1 (mod pq)` для всех `m` из диапазона `[1,pq-1]`

Пример. Возьмём `p = 11` и `q = 31`. Для это пары `N = 341` и `phi(N) = 300`. Возьмём в качестве публичного ключа `e = 7`. Если брать традиционное описание RSA, приведённое в русской Википедии, то мы должны взять `d = 43`. Действительно, `7*43 = 301 == 1 mod 300`. Можно в лоб проверить, что для любого `m` из диапазона [1, 340] выполняется шифрование-расшифрование RSA: `(m**7)**43 == m (mod 341)`

А теперь попробуем провести ту же проверку для числа `d1 = 13`. Возьмем пайтон и посчитаем все возможные значения `(m**7)**13 - m (mod 341)`:

```
>>> set([((m**7)**13) % 341 - m for m in range(1,341)])
{0}
```

Что означает этот ноль? Что `d1` так же является приватным ключом для `e=7`. Более того, приватными ключами будут числа 73, 103, 133 и так далее. Все эти числа объединяет тот факт, что они отстоят от 13 на число, кратное 30-ти. А что такое 30? Это наименьшее общее кратное чисел 10 (т.е. `p-1`) и 30 (т.е. `q-1`)

[В реальной жизни](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/c8830891e6cb8d0782986662ca50b8fa7c97f49f/crypto/rsa/rsa_sp800_56b_gen.c#L247) в качестве `d` выбирают такое число, что `d*e == 1 mod( lcm(p-1,q-1) )`. Ссылка ведёт на функцию генерации приватных ключей RSA в openssl. Можете убедиться, относительно какого модуля инвертируют `e`.

Теперь про то, как считают `d` в видео.

Более строго там должно быть так - давайте подберём `k` таким, чтобы `k*Phi(n)+1` нацело делится на `e`. То есть `k=2` справедливо только для их примера. В моём примере с 11 и 31 `k=1`.

Почему так. Если `d = (k*Phi(n)+1)/e` - целое, то `d*e = k*Phi(n)+1`, что означает `d*e` сравнимо с единицей по модулю `Phi(n)`. Другими словами, `d` есть инвертированное `e` по модулю функции Эйлера.

Такое `k` существует всегда, если `e` и `Phi(n)` взаимно просты.

Так инвертировать можно, но чудовищно неэффективно.

**UPDATE**

Как же инвертировать эффективно.

Алгоритм с перебором `k` имеет среднюю сложность порядка `n`, где `n` - модуль, относительно которого производится инвертирование. В случае больших `n` этот процесс не закончится никогда.

На практике пользуются [расширенным алгоритмом Евклида](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0). Его сложность в худшем случае порядка логарифма большего числа. По этой ссылке я взял реализацию для Python и выполнил код `bezout(30,7)`. Получил `(-3, 13, 1)`, что означает `-3*30 + 13*7 = 1`.

Заменяем равенство на сравнение по модулю и получаем, что `13*7` сравнимо с 1 по модулю 30. Следовательно, 13 - обратное к 7 число по модулю 30. Ответ найден за 3 шага, перебор за 13. В случае инвертирования 7 по модулю 300 (значение функции Эйлера для 11*31) обратное находится тоже за 3 шага, а перебором за 43. Ещё пример неэффективности перебора `k`: инвертирование 7 по модулю 1009 (первое простое большее 1000) алгоритмом Евклида выполняется за 2 шага, а перебором с единицы 865. Перебирать можно, но не нужно.

Comment: Подскажите, а как вы получили 13? И что значит неэффективно инвертировать, имеется ввиду что находить методом перебора k ? Нужно использовать специальный алгоритм?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов добавил про инвертирование.